# Cannot start delayed_job service

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I use delayed_job to do some work on background process. I run with the same project in local machine and it works fine. However, I run it on the server causing problem.
I have another project using delayed_job also and it works fine in the same server that cause the problem.

Below is the exception:

```
exit
["/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:167:in `exit'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:167:in `call_as_daemon'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:254:in `start_proc'",
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:294:in `start'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:193", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `call'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `catch_exceptions'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:192:in `run_proc'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.3/lib/delayed/command.rb:71:in `run_process'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.3/lib/delayed/command.rb:65:in `daemonize'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.3/lib/delayed/command.rb:63:in `times'", 
"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.3/lib/delayed/command.rb:63:in `daemonize'",
 "script/delayed_job:5"]
delayed_job: process with pid 16880 started.
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly it does say 'process with pid 16880 started'. If you run this:

```
ps -Alf | grep 16880
```

Does it show you that the process is running? In which case I'd consult the log files it is writing out.

You might not have privileges to start the process? Try

```
sudo RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

It is not a good idea to keep things that way on the server - but it should tell you if it's a problem with user permissions for whichever user is running the dj process.

And on top of that, make sure that you haven't accidentally got several instances of the delayed_job daemon running. Not sure what the process will be called, but you can use ps and grep to find all instances and then kill them:

```
ps -Alf | grep delayed_job
```

Then, let's say you see several instances running, and the first has a process ID of 123456

```
kill -HUP 123456
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. But after I run command start service then I check by using "ps aux | grep 'delayed_job'" and it show nothing.

Comment: It might just be labelled as ruby, try a | grep ruby